# Django API beyond simple data handling

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a django application that deploys the model logic and data handling through the administration.

I also have in the same project a python file (scriptcl.py) that makes use of the model data to perform heavy calculations that take some time, per example 5 secs, to be processed.

I have migrated the project to the cloud and now I need an API to call this file (scriptcl.py) passing parameters, process the computation accordingly to the parameters and data of the DB (maintained in the admin) and then respond back.

All examples of the django DRF that I've seen so far only contain authentication and data handling (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

Could anyone suggest an idea to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a feedback to this, the approach that I took was to build another API using flask and normal python scripts.

I also used sqlalchemy to access the database and retrieve the necessary data.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion correct approach would be using Celery to perform this calculations asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Write a class which inherits from DRF APIView which handles authentication, write whatever logic you want or call whichever function, Get the final result and send back the JsonReposen. But as you mentioned if the Api takes more time to respond. Then you might have to think of some thing else. Like giving back a request_id and hit that server with the request_id every 5seconds to get the data or something like that.